# How to add image to buttonrow Swift Eureka

Tags: swift2, eureka-forms

Im new to Eureka form framework (Swift 2) and Im trying to set the background color of the cell and also add a left icon like the image below.

[image]

My actual code is:

```
<<< ButtonRow() { (row: ButtonRow) -> Void in
                row.title = "Access"

                }  .onCellSelection({ (cell, row) in
                    self.showAlert()
                })
```

> Any clue?

Answer (score 6):

This should work for you:

```
.cellSetup { cell, row in
     cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha: 1.0)
     cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "name_of_image_in_assets")
}
```

Replace the "0.00" with your desired UIColor RGB settings.